# combine two pictures(different size) horizontally?

Tags: numpy, opencv

I have 2 pictures, need to combine them horizontally. I know numpy and cv2(opencv) should help me to do this. But don't know how.
I used

```
img1 = cv2.imread(file1)
img2 = cv2.imread(file2)
```

the 2 images' shape are `(2048, 1334, 3)` and `(720, 1200, 3)`

How could I do this? when I open These 2 images, they have similar height, different width.

I only know if the 2 pics have the same size, then just use concate, but my 2 pics are different sizes.

For the final output, I want to have them keep their own width, height choose the biggest/smallest...

So I imagine the final output should maybe 2/3 width one picture, 1/3 width the other pic which is totally good. I don't need these 2 are evenly distributed. Just keep their own width. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to either trim a bit of the bottom of the taller image or add some black pixels.

In order to trim a part of the image, you can do:

```
trimmed = image2[:image1.shape[0],:,:]
```

This keeps only the lines from 0 up to the height of `image1`.

Or, you can add some black pixels:

```
black = np.zeros(image1.shape[0] - image2.shape[0], image1.shape[1])
image2 = np.hstack(image2, black)
```

And then you vertically concatenate.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my question.
Basically use `cv2.resize()`function to resize the images
Then simply concatenate them horizontally or vertically. 
Just change the axis.

```
img1 = cv2.imread('xxx.png')
img2 = cv2.imread('yyy.jpg')
```

then compare `img1.shape()` and `img2.shape()`
Use resize()function to make them width the same or height the same.

```
vis = np.concatenate((img1, img2), axis=1)
cv2.imwrite('out.png', vis)
```